# How can I get iptables to block YouTube packets?

Tags: iptables

I have a Raspberry Pi and use it as a router. I would like to construct a packet-filtered network, but I'm not sure how to achieve this.

What I did is like this:

```
sudo iptables -w -N YOUTUBE
sudo iptables -w -A YOUTUBE -j REJECT

sudo iptables -w -I OUTPUT  -p all -m string --string "youtube.com" --algo kmp -j YOUTUBE
sudo iptables -w -I FORWARD -p all -m string --string "youtube.com" --algo kmp -j YOUTUBE

sudo iptables -w -I OUTPUT  -p all -m string --string "googlevideo.com" --algo kmp -j YOUTUBE
sudo iptables -w -I FORWARD -p all -m string --string "googlevideo.com" --algo kmp -j YOUTUBE

# ... (some other domains)
```

This is an example of filtering YouTube.

When I open a browser in incognito mode and head over to YouTube, my computer can't reach it. Its behavior is what I expect.

However, when I try it in non-incognito mode, it can still access YouTube no matter how much time passes.

Why does that behavior occur, and how can I resolve it?

By the way, I tried blocking YouTube with Dnsmasq, and it worked successfully. But what I want to do now is to restrict it at the TCP/IP level.

Thank you.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I have my Raspberry Pi installed on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up resolving it by myself.

It seems that the letter `.` inside the string is converted to the number that describes how many letters the subsequent lasts.

I updated the previous commands to the following, and it appears to work well.

```
sudo iptables -w -I OUTPUT  -p all -m string --hex-string "youtube|03|com" --algo bm -j YOUTUBE
sudo iptables -w -I FORWARD -p all -m string --hex-string "youtube|03|com" --algo bm -j YOUTUBE

sudo iptables -w -I OUTPUT  -p all -m string --hex-string "googlevideo|03|com" --algo bm -j YOUTUBE
sudo iptables -w -I FORWARD -p all -m string --hex-string "googlevideo|03|com" --algo bm -j YOUTUBE
```

I'm still not sure why the previous one also works fine in incognito mode, though.